# SQL - need a query for the last_date for each user, max_date, min_date

Tags: mysql, sql

The original table looks like:

```
id   date        name
----------------------
11   01-2021     'aaa'
11   03-2020     'bbb'
11   01-2019     'ccc'
11   12-2017     'ddd'
12   02-2011     'kkk'
12   05-2015     'lll'
12   12-2020     'mmm'
```

the expected output:

```
id.   min_date.  max_date   name
---------------------------------
11    12-2017    01-2021    'aaa'
12    02-2011    12-2020    'mmm'
```

I need to have, min, max dates and the name that corresponds to the max_date.
I know a way to get min, max dates and separately how to get the date corresponding to the max_date (using ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY...)), but cannot figure out how to combine both together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `ROW_NUMBER` along with pivoting logic to select the name corresponding the max date per each `id`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    id,
    MIN(date) AS min_date,
    MAX(date) AS max_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN name END) AS name
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that your current `date` column appears to be text.  Don't store your dates as text, instead use a proper date column.

Comment: It works, thank you. a question about your code. Can I use "WITH" and then create a VIEW instead of just SELECT statement? CREATE VIEW tmp_view AS (select id, MIN(date).... )? It does not seem to work. I had to create another view instead of a temporary table with WITH.

Comment: @user1298416 If you want to create a view, then just inline the CTE.  In other words, instead of doing `FROM cte`, use `FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() ... ) t`

Comment: Yes, this way I know, it is just so much more clearer if I could split in separate blocks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with inlining the CTE...I mean, it's not like we have a lot of code inside this particular CTE, right?

Comment: Well, I have 4 nested ones. I just trimmed my code a lot to ask the question. Nested works, but it gets very unreadable when there are more than 2 select statements.

Answer (score 1):

This below query should work

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 t1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          min(date) AS min_date,
          max(date) AS max_date
   FROM tbl1
   GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.date = t2.max_date
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aebd9236a3b014325e6f092fa8929170)